# I'm Working with the action call in the android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've done the code for placing the call and the thing is i want to place the call from the number which i stored in the database means i want dynamic calling action in my app...
Hoe do i do that....Any Help would be appreciated......
THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!!!

My code for placing the callsss......is right under below....

```
cardView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9855956530"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");

            } else {

                Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);

            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");

        }
    }

});
```

And i used the fragments in this app
Database is Sqlite Database

Comment: parse the data, from the database on click of cardview and then do the above logic to open the dialer. It's so simple, what did you not understand

Comment: thanks but i want to say that i creared the form from where user can enter his/her own number and after that number willbe used for the calling or any messages by fetching from the database